# C# Replace all characters in string with value of character key in dictionary

Tags: c#, string, encryption, char

hi i have this dictionary

```
Dictionary<char, string> keys = new Dictionary<char, string>();
keys.Add("a", "23");
keys.Add("A", "95");
keys.Add("d", "12");
keys.Add("D", "69");
```

and for example this string

```
string text = "Dad";
```

i want to encrypt the string with dictionary keys and values!
the final encrypted string will be:
**692312**

anyone can  help?!

Comment: Shouldn't your dictionary map `Dictionary<char,int>` or `Dictionary<char,string>`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes it can be `Dictionary<char.string>`

Comment: What is your question? This is not a "write my code for me" service where you give us requirements and we come back with a working product. You gave us requirements, we need a question about c# code. You can iterate a string like so: `foreach (char c in text) { }`, and when your dictionary contains characters instead of strings you can do things like `if (keys.ContainsKey(c) { append keys.Value to output string}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq* and `string.Concat`:

```
// Dictionary<string, string> - actual keys are strings
Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

keys.Add("a", "23");
keys.Add("A", "95");
keys.Add("d", "12");
keys.Add("D", "69");

string result = string.Concat(text.Select(c => keys[c.ToString()]));
```

a better design is to declare `keys` as `Dictionary<char, string>`:

```
Dictionary<char, string> keys = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
  {'a', "23"},
  {'A', "95"},
  {'d', "12"},
  {'D', "69"},    
};

...

string result = string.Concat(text.Select(c => keys[c]));
```

**Edit:** proving that *each* character is encoded as a **fixed length** string (`2` in the example) it's easy to decode:

```
Dictionary<string, char> decode = keys
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key);

int fixedSize = decode.First().Key.Length;

string decoded = string.Concat(Enumerable
  .Range(0, result.Length / fixedSize)
  .Select(i => decode[result.Substring(i * fixedSize, fixedSize)]));
```

Comment: @Artjom B: if it's guaranteed that each character is encoded as a fixed length string (`2` in the example), then decryption will be quite easy to implement.

Comment: @Artjom B: you have to modify the code a bit (see my edit) since `fixedSize` is not `1`: `Substring` required

Answer (score 0):

If your plaintext is quite large, you might also find it more performant to use a StringBuilder, instead of plain string concatenation.

```
StringBuilder cyphertext = new StringBuilder();

foreach(char letter in text)
{
    cyphertext.Append(keys[letter]);
}
```