# How can I change each character in a string to a specific symbol using C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Basically, I have a string called data, which contains a sentence written by user input.

I want to be able to output that exact sentence but with each letter in the sentence being changed to a symbol based on the letter. For example, the letter A will be changed to the “&” symbol (random example).

However, I can’t figure out how to scan the string and change each letter to the symbol. I’m not sure what approach to take and how to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: @dxiv Similar, but not the same problem - in this question the OP wants to use a replacement map on a per-character replacements, but the linked duplicates concern only single replacements.

Comment: How far did you get before what went wrong, please?

Comment: A better duplicate would be [C# Replace all characters in string with value of character key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43128170/3744182), which shows creating a new string by remapping the characters in the old string via a dictionary lookup.  Agree that is a duplicate?

Comment: @Dai My bad, I misread the question. I cannot change the duplicate target so I retracted that vote, though I think the other question linked in the previous comment could qualify as a duplicate, instead.

Answer (score 4):

`String` values are immutable, so you need to use a `StringBuilder` to create the output string, character-by-character. The character-replacement map can be a simple `Dictionary<Char,Char>` instance.

Like so:

```
static String SubstitutionCipher( String input, IReadOnlyDictionary<Char,Char> map )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: input.Length );
    
    foreach( Char c in input )
    {
        if( map.TryGetValue( c, out Char replacement ) )
        {
            sb.Append( replacement );
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append( c );
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();

}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    String input = Console.ReadLine();

    Dictionary<Char,Char> map = new Dictionary<Char,Char>()
    {
        { 'A', '@' },
        { 'B', 'ß' },
        { 'C', '' }
    };

    String output = SubstitutionCipher( input, map );

    Console.WriteLine( output ) ;
}
```